# Panache Mongodb- generics handling

Tags: java, mongodb, generics, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I would like to store a generic object type in a MongoDB entity. However, when I attempt to do this, I get a nasty error about the entity having non-specialized members.

My entity:

```java
@MongoEntity(collection = "inventoryItem")
public class InventoryItemEntity<S extends Stored> extends OurMongoEntity<InventoryItem<S>> {
}
```

`OurMongoEntity`, used to streamline creating entities, as I want to use the same pojo classes for everything, and not need separate classes for storage:

```java
public abstract class OurMongoEntity<T> extends PanacheMongoEntity {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public T obj;
    
    ...
}
```

This model worked, until I decided to make the `InventoryItem` class a generic for different types of item:

```java
InventoryItem<S extends Stored>

InventoryItemAmt extends InventoryItem<AmountStored>
InventoryItemTracked extends InventoryItem<TrackedStored>
```

The error I get when attempting to persist the object:

```
An exception occurred when encoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Encoding a InventoryItemEntity: 'InventoryItemEntity()' failed with the following exception:

InventoryItemEntity contains generic types that have not been specialised.
Top level classes with generic types are not supported by the PojoCodec.

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An exception occurred when encoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Encoding a InventoryItemEntity: 'InventoryItemEntity()' failed with the following exception:

InventoryItemEntity contains generic types that have not been specialised.
Top level classes with generic types are not supported by the PojoCodec.

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.
```

I have attempted making my own Codec, thinking that I could simply provide a way to resolve the different types of `InventoryItem`, but that did not resolve things:

```java
public class InventoryItemCodecProvider implements CodecProvider {
    @Override
    public <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz, CodecRegistry registry) {
        if(InventoryItemAmt.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)){
            return (Codec<T>) registry.get(InventoryItemAmt.class);
        }
        if(InventoryItemTracked.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)){
            return (Codec<T>) registry.get(InventoryItemTracked.class);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I suppose I could try a couple things....

- Implement a codec for the whole entity, judging the type held, and return a non-generic codec. Thing here is providing a codec for an entire entity feels weird. Also unsure how I can implement it.
- Adjust to have two entities; one for `InventoryItemAmt` and one for `InventoryItemTracked`. This has its own problems of "which entity do I use for searching?" etc.

What would be best practice in this case?

Comment: Well first things first, did you check that your codec was being call?, second, having a generic solution is not going to help you searching because even though you can search and retrieve documents, later you will need to map that to java classes, this is why you can provide to mongo the expected class. You are using the autoResolver, but you can do the mapping manually in the response. If you don't know to map from mongo to java, the mongodb java driver neither. This is where the codec can help you with specific classes or just retrieve Document class instances and do the mapping by hand

Comment: Yeah, I was seeing that my codec was being called, but the codec was never passed the specific type, only the abstract class which can't be used to differentiate and pass back the appropriate codec... For now I have resigned to needing to combine the subclasses and use that, and have extra validation that each object is used appropriately, as I would need to deal with Jackson for the same reasons as Mongo. Left the question here in case someone who knows more can answer anyways